# Improve parallelism c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I've developed a simple data migration console tool. using C#, Linq and EF.
This tool get all data I want to move from place A to B.
The code is something like this:

```
var data = dataAccess.GetData()
 Parallel.ForEach(data, currentdata =>
 { 
   //Do some business, and insert data
 });
```

As I know parallel foreach handles everythig in order to take the advantage of parallelism using all cores of the procesor and threads as possible in the most profitable way.

So I tried this tool with a huge amount of data, and migration process takes about 5h.

Then, I decided to try other idea.

I've generated 4 consoles.exe of this proyect, making a modification, now  each one takes a quarter of data.

Eg: Total data is about 40 millions registers to migrate, console 1 migrates from 0 to 10M, console 2 from 10M to 20M, console 3 from 20M to 30M and console 4 from 30M to 40M
Then I runned this consoles, one on each core of my processor, and guess what, it takes less than a half to migrate everything.

How could it be possible if supposedly parallel foreach should be the best aproach?

Any idea to replicate this improvement just with one console?

Thank you.

EDIT: 
Now I'm trying this, previously I chunked the data:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            int cpuCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int offset = process.Threads.Count;
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[cpuCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart( migrateChunk))
                { IsBackground = true };
                t.Start();
            }

            process.Refresh();
            for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i)
            {
                process.Threads[i + offset].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(i+1);
            }
```

Do you think is a good approach? Because I dont see any improvement from parallel Foreach. Even I tried to attach all proccesses to the same core but dont see any change.
thanks

Comment: I think you should add a more complete code sample for people to help you better.

Comment: When you profile your code, how many threads are being used by your Parallel.For implementation ?

Comment: I don't know because I thought parallel.ForEach takes care of it? should I do something else to configure it???

Comment: If you mainly push data from one source to a destination, this is mainly I/O bound (network, drives, etc). But the task parallel library is focused on CPU bound stuff (parallelize computation of a value).

Comment: A possible reason could be that there is some part of the code that is not really parallelized, in the sense that running the code on two threads will make them work suboptimal, like using some piece of data where there is a `lock(x) { ... }` around a piece of code. These things typically don't take effect across process boundaries, but only inside the process.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is on

```
var data = dataAccess.GetData()
```

let said to retrieve the 40 mil of data is take 4 mins, and retrieve the 10 mil of data is take 1 mins, so the 10 mil console apps start moving the data when the 40 mil still retrieving the data from the database.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(data, currentdata => { //Do some business, and insert data });
```

for this part, you might want to check out the Parallel documentation, basically, the parallel will get the data and divide into small chunk and spread the data to the processors to process it.
1. [Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library) 
2. [Parallel Partition of Work](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/26/parallelism-in-net-part-5-partitioning-of-work/)